# Problem installing "toxiclibs" library on Processing

Tags: processing, visualization, mpu6050

I want to install the "toxiclibs" library on Processing, but when I go to "Sketch" -> "Add library", I don't find it among the examples !

I looked on the internet and found the github link for it. Now how can I manually install it because I had tried to copy the library many times in different folders (the "library" folder for example which seems obvious) but nothing changed and I still get the message "No toxi" library found !

I used Processing 4 and 3 and had the same issue.

Comment: Should be listed for you to install with menuBar Tools/ManageTools/Libraries tab.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the toxiclibs have not been updated in a while therefore the library is not integrated with the Contribution Manager in Processing.

Additionally it's a collection of libraries with a slightly different structure to simpler Processing libraries.

That being said you should be able to:

1. Download [toxiclibs-complete-0021.zip](https://github.com/postspectacular/toxiclibs/releases/download/0021/toxiclibs-complete-0021.zip) (from the [github repo's releases page](https://github.com/postspectacular/toxiclibs/releases/tag/0021))
2. Unzip the contents to `Documents/Processing/libraries`
3. Try to use a sketch or open a an example (via Examples > Contributed Libraries)

I'm suspecting you mainly need the [Quaternion](https://toxiclibs.org/docs/core/toxi/geom/Quaternion.html) class to convert the MPU6050 data to a 4x4 matrix to use in Processing ?
(Personally I haven't used MPU6050 for 6DOF, I've used [BNO055](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor/processing-test) and even the Adafruit guide recomends their [WebSerial Model Viewer](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-bno055-absolute-orientation-sensor/webserial-visualizer), probably due to the lessened support with the Processing/toxiclibs setup ?)